# Use POST or GET Request From Static URLs in Template in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, custom-routes

Please bear with me, as I'm new to programming in Rails and in general.  I have a very limited understanding of how the models, views, controllers function but I've been learning as fast as I can.

I am having trouble with how I can generate semi-static intermediate pages based off the data I already have.  Right now it's just a zip code search, a page with a list of results and a shop page.  I want it structured by State-city-list-shop

In my database are shop locations that have been geocoded and made accessible on the client side via zip code search.  So I'm dealing with a Shops controller that has the usual scaffold type setup so a url looks like /shops/1 for the show view.  What I would like is shops/alaska/anchorage/the-name-of-the-shop with breadcrumbs.

I don't have a "States" or "Cities" controller which is how I would assume you'd have to do it in order to get the routes built.

I made static State template pages, and for each State I list the cities with the links looking like [City](/shop/state/city/).  I have an index.html file in each of the State folders but there's nothing in /shop/state/city

I did it like that because I can get results from this:

**/shops/find_shops?=zip=City&Distance=5**
Which if I could get the same result for **/state/city/shops** I'd be happy.

Because then I could click one of the shops in that list and it would take me to the shops page which is **/shops/7499** (:id)  and it would be better to have **/state/city/shop-name**

Here's the **Shop controller** - the admin is simply protecting the public from editing the shop address info.  As you'll see it's taking a csv file, parsing and saving to the database.

```
    def admin_index
    #@shops = Shop.find(:all)

    @shops = Shop.paginate( :per_page => 35, 
                   :page => params[:page])

    @shops_to_geocode = Shop.fetch_not_geocoded
  end

  def geocode_shops
    @shops_to_geocode = Shop.fetch_not_geocoded
    cnt = 0
    for shop in @shops_to_geocode
      shop.geocode_raw_address
      shop.save!
    end
    redirect_to :action => 'admin_index'
  end

  def upload_file
    file_path = params[:file_path]
    if file_path
      Shop.import( file_path )
    end
    redirect_to :action => 'admin_index' 
  end

  # GET /shops
  # GET /shops.xml
  def index
    @zip = params[:zip]
    @distance = params[:distance]

    if @zip && @distance 
      @shops = Shop.find(:all, :origin => @zip, :conditions => ["distance < ?", @distance])
      logger.debug( "found #{@shops.length} shops" )

      if @shops.length == 0
        geo = GeoKit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode( @zip )
        errors.add(:address, "Could not Geocode address") if !geo.success
        @centerLat, @centerLng = geo.lat,geo.lng if geo.success
      else
        @centerLat = @shops[0].lat
        @centerLng = @shops[0].lng
      end
    else
      @shops = []

      geo = GeoKit::Geocoders::IpGeocoder.geocode(request.remote_ip)
      if geo.success
        @centerLat, @centerLng = geo.lat,geo.lng 
      else
        logger.debug( "unable to geocode remote ip" )
        @centerLat = 42 
        @centerLng = -120 
      end
    end

    if @distance.nil?
      @distance = 5
    end
```

And Here's the **Shop.rb**

```
require 'net/http'

class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base

  acts_as_mappable

  DATA_FILE_COLS =
    [
      "---",
      "Site",
      "Zip Search",
      "Shop",
      "Address",
      "Phone",
      "Make",
      "Affiliations",
      "Specialties",
      "Amenities",
      "Timestap",
    ]

  FIELDS = 
    {
      "---" => "-1",
      "Site" => "-1",
      "Zip Search" => "-1",
      "Shop" => "name",
      "Address" => "raw_address",
      "Phone" => "phone_number",
      "Make" => "make",
      "Affiliations" => "affiliations",
      "Specialties" => "specialties",
      "Amenities" => "amenities",
      "Timestap" => "-1"
    }


  def full_address
    "#{address_1} #{city} #{state} #{postal_code}"
  end

  def valid_for_geocoding?
    rtn = true 
    if self.full_address.nil? || self.full_address.to_s.empty? 
       rtn = false 
    end

    return rtn 
  end

  def geocode_address
    geo = GeoKit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode( full_address )
    errors.add(:address, "Could not Geocode address") if !geo.success
    self.lat, self.lng = geo.lat,geo.lng if geo.success
  end

  def geocode_raw_address
        geo = GeoKit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode(self.raw_address)
        if ( geo.success )
          self.address_1 = geo.street_address
          self.city = geo.city
          self.state = geo.state
          self.postal_code = geo.zip
          self.lat = geo.lat
          self.lng = geo.lng
        end
  end

  def self.import( file_path )
    url = 'http://example.com'
    #file = '/filename.txt'
    file = file_path


    response = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(url + file))
    body = response.body
    lines = body.split("\r\n")

    line_cnt = 0

    lines.each { |line| 
      if line_cnt > 1
        words = line.split("\"")
        cnt = 0
        shop_atrbs = Hash.new
        words.each { |word|
          if word != ","
            #puts "#{fields[cnt]} : #{word.strip}"
            field = FIELDS[DATA_FILE_COLS[cnt]]
            if field != "-1"
              shop_atrbs[field] = word.strip
            end
            cnt = cnt + 1
          end
        }
        shop = Shop.new
        shop.update_attributes(shop_atrbs)
        geo = GeoKit::Geocoders::MultiGeocoder.geocode(shop.raw_address)
        shop.address_1 = geo.street_address
        shop.city = geo.city
        shop.state = geo.state
        shop.postal_code = geo.zip
        shop.lat = geo.lat
        shop.lng = geo.lng
        shop.save

      end
      line_cnt = line_cnt + 1
    }    #f.each{ |line| puts '#{f.lineno}: #{line}' }
  end

  def self.fetch_not_geocoded
    find( :all,
    :conditions => ['lat IS NULL || lng IS NULL || lat = ? || lng = ?', "", ""],
    :limit => 10000)
  end

  def self.find_for_sitemap(offset, limit)
    find( :all, 
          :select => 'id, name, updated_at',
          :order => 'updated_at DESC',
          :offset => offset,
          :limit => limit )
  end

end
```

So, what I want to have work is - /Alaska/Anchorage/Shops-List/ (clean URL)

What I can do right now is - 
/find_shops?zip=anchorage&distance=5

Lastly, this is rails 2.3.2 and I've spent so much time trying to get it converted to rails 3.0 but haven't had success with that yet.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read the Rails Routing guide "Rails Routing from the Outside In"? In particular [section 4](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/routing.html#regular-routes) covers how you might achieve this.

Comment: I just saw that the other day and was trying to see how it might apply.  The problem is that I am never quite sure if it's the right solution and I have probably looked straight the answer but didn't realize it.

Comment: I've been trying to understand routing better so I've been trying different variations like 'match' and 'resources do' and => shops#index.  I was checking out the error controller where you can set def what pages display on an error.

Comment: Ok, maybe Route Globbing is the answer.  *a/foo/*b => test#index .  So the *a could be shops/state  -  foo could be city -  and *b could be address/shop-name  - so you would need the params[:a] for state and params[:b] for shop-name?  Params meaning the id I suspect?